# How Implement on the fly augmentation in the tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-augmentation

I want implement augmentation in a 3D dataset with an tensorflow model.

the augmentation  function is like this:

```py
    def augmentation(img, label):
            
            p = .5
            print('augmentation')
            
            if random.random() > p:
                img = tf.numpy_function(augment_noise, [img], tf.double)
                
            if random.random() > p:
                img = tf.numpy_function(flip_x, [img], tf.double)
    
            if random.random() > p:
                img = tf.numpy_function(augment_scale, [img], tf.double)
    
            if random.random() > p:
                img = tf.numpy_function(distort_elastic_cv2, [img], tf.double)    
            
           
            img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
            
            return img, label
```

The augment functions is not implemented in tensorflow.

Tensorflow code for using this function is as follow:

```py
ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_train, label_train))
ds_valid = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_val, label_val))


batch_size = 16
repeat_count = int((1000 * batch_size)/len(image_train))
# AUTOTUNE =  tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE # tf.data.AUTOTUNE
AUTOTUNE = 16

# Augment the on the fly during training.
ds_train = (
    ds_train.shuffle(len(ds_train)).repeat(repeat_count)
    .map(augmentation, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    .batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
)


ds_valid = (
    ds_valid.batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
)

initial_epoch = 0
epochs = 1000
H = model.fit(ds_train, validation_data=ds_valid,initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
               epochs = epochs,
              callbacks = chkpts, use_multiprocessing=False, workers=1, verbose=2)
```

I want in each epoch randomly select about 1000 batch from the dataset, and then augment them on the. The I calculate `repeat_count` to create 1000 batch with size of `batch_size`.

The problem is that I don't know is model call augmentation function in each epoch and implies it to each images of the batch(I mean 16*1000 images in each epoch), so I added `print` in the `augmentation` function, that it only printed one times, not in each epoch, or for each image.
Is the augmentation function call 16*1000 times in each epoch?

Also the Utilization of cpu and gpu is vary in each run of the code. some time the Utilization of cpu is about 25% and gpu is 30, but in almost of runs it is 100% and 5.

How can solve the two problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your string is printed once because it's calling once to make a Tensorflow graph. If you use `tf.print` to print, it will be part of the graph so it will print every time.

Copy/paste this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image
import numpy as np
import random

imgs = np.stack([load_sample_image('flower.jpg') for i in range(4*4)], axis=0)

def augmentation(img):      
        p = .5
        tf.print('augmentation successful!')  
        img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
        return img 
    

ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(imgs)


batch_size = 16
repeat_count = 10
AUTOTUNE = 16

ds_train = (
    ds_train.shuffle(len(ds_train)).repeat(repeat_count)
    .map(augmentation, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    .batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
)

for i in ds_train:
    pass
```

```
augmentation successful!
augmentation successful!
augmentation successful!
augmentation successful!
augmentation successful!
augmentation successful!
augmentation successful!
augmentation successful!
augmentation successful!
```